# Sichuanese : any tips to learn some vocabulary?

Tags: vocabulary

大家好，

我想学四川话。我已经会普通话但是我迫不及待学四川话。
除了要得意外，我不太熟悉其他词汇儿。在哪里可以找到四川话的词汇？
你们四川人一般还有什么很有用的？
请原谅我的中文，我尽力写得很好。 ：）
I also wanna mention that I already know how to pronounce the Ch->c, Sh->s ...etc Just looking for great expressions or vocabulary
Any help is greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can start by watching some TV shows, for instance:

- [下课了，要雄起](https://so.youku.com/search_video/q_%E4%B8%8B%E8%AF%BE%E4%BA%86%EF%BC%8C%E8%A6%81%E9%9B%84%E8%B5%B7?spm=a2ha1.12325017.#qheader_search~10)
- [戳锅漏](https://so.youku.com/search_video/q_%E6%88%B3%E9%94%85%E6%BC%8F?spm=a2ha1.12325017.#qheader_search~10)
- [傻儿司令](https://so.youku.com/search_video/q_%E5%93%88%E5%84%BF%E5%8F%B8%E4%BB%A4)
- [耙耳朵的幸福生活](https://www.bilibili.com/video/av6586728/index_3.html#page=1)

Most of them are subtitled but more dialectical words will be translated into Mandarin in the subtitles.

---

There are also many books

- [四川方言日历(2019)](https://www.amazon.cn/dp/B07JYVMZZV/ref=sr_1_10?ie=UTF8&qid=1547193530&sr=8-10&keywords=%E5%9B%9B%E5%B7%9D%E6%96%B9%E8%A8%80)
- [漫画四川方言](https://www.amazon.cn/dp/B012CL5UU4/ref=sr_1_17?ie=UTF8&qid=1547193530&sr=8-17&keywords=%E5%9B%9B%E5%B7%9D%E6%96%B9%E8%A8%80)
- [老成都漫画系列:成都话](https://www.amazon.cn/dp/B01M8QXN77/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1547193609&sr=8-1&keywords=%E6%88%90%E9%83%BD%E8%AF%9D)
- [Chinese Lessons For First Year Students in West China by Kilborn, Omar L. (Omar Leslie), 1867-1920](https://archive.org/details/chineselessonsfo00kilbuoft)
- [Western Mandarin or, The Spoken Language of Western China; with Syllabic and English Indexes by Grainger, Adam](https://archive.org/details/westernmandarino00graiuoft)

and dictionaries:

- [四川方言词典](https://www.amazon.cn/dp/B00J7EC1DY/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1547193530&sr=8-1&keywords=%E5%9B%9B%E5%B7%9D%E6%96%B9%E8%A8%80)
- [四川方言词源](https://www.amazon.cn/dp/B00MDC00EE/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1547193530&sr=8-2&keywords=%E5%9B%9B%E5%B7%9D%E6%96%B9%E8%A8%80)
- [成都方言词汇](https://www.amazon.cn/dp/B0011CPLA0/ref=sr_1_6?ie=UTF8&qid=1547193530&sr=8-6&keywords=%E5%9B%9B%E5%B7%9D%E6%96%B9%E8%A8%80)
- [成都方言](https://www.amazon.cn/dp/B00YBYXV7U/ref=sr_1_8?ie=UTF8&qid=1547193530&sr=8-8&keywords=%E5%9B%9B%E5%B7%9D%E6%96%B9%E8%A8%80)

---

Nothing, though, beats spending time with actual native speakers and interacting with them.

Some of the most common words include:

- 巴适 = 很棒
- 安逸 = 舒服
- 牙尖 = 八卦
- 雄起 = 加油
- 洋盘 = 洋气
- 子 = 干嘛
- 将就 = 凑合
- 摆龙门阵 = 聊天儿
- 宝器 = 傻瓜
- 耳朵 = 妻管严

There are many lists online too like:

- [标准四川话300句](http://www.360doc.com/content/13/1008/11/872290_319791006.shtml)
- [四川话怎么说，经典四川话，常用四川话大全](http://app.myzaker.com/news/article.php?&pk=54e53be31bc8e08257000000&app_id=400000&sharechannel=wx)

Comment: Wow ! Thanks for your great input. Yeah, I know some people from Sichuan and wanna surprise them. ^^ 很感激，谢谢 

Comment: @Mat you can also look up the wechat official account: PricklyAsh刺椒 - they have a bunch of articles and stuff you can read.